# Using Custom validators in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to use custom validator to compare if the end time is greater than the start time.

code:

```
function timeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(control.value) || control.get('fromTime').value > control.get('toTime').value)) {
          return { 'ageRange': true };
      }
      return null;
  };
}
```

From formgroup

```
toTime: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, timeValidator(this.fromTime,this.toTime)]),
```

I'm getting a error once I run this like: `Cannot read property 'value' of null` on the line `if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(control.value) || control.get('fromTime').value > control.get('toTime').value))`

I need some help in fixing this. Thank you

Comment: can you share the code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: You are calling the validator instead of passing the function as a parameter

Comment: Thank you, an example would be great to learn.@AvinKavish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom validator should be put at FormGroup level not FormControl level. Also you should pass the function in as an argument, meaning without the () brackets because timeValidator is a callback function. () tells the js engine to execute the function. But what you want is pass in the function as an argument, so it could be executed later.

either

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
...
this.form = this.fb.group({
    fromTime: [''],
    toTime: ['']
}, { validator: timeValidator})
```

OR

```
 form = new FormGroup({
     toTime: new FormControl(null),
     fromTime: new FormControl(null),
 }, { validator: timeValidator})
```

Your custom validator also shouldn't be returning a function. It should be returning a name:boolean key-value pair. E.g. isEndGTStart: true or null if false

E.g.

```
export function timeValidator(fg: FormGroup){
    const fromTime = fg.get("fromTime").value;
    const toTime = fg.get("toTime).value;

    return toTime > fromTime ? { isEndGTStart: true } : null
}
```